# How to add a constant into LINQ query in BLtoolkit

Tags: jquery, linq, bltoolkit

Im trying to add a constant to a LINQ query in BLtoolkit.

```
var query = dbManager.Table.Select(x=>new { x.column, cnst = 1 });
```

but in the result there is only 'column' column, but no 'cnst' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this form instead:

```
var query = from x in dbManager.Table
        select new
        {
            x.column,
            cnst = 1
        };
```

Comment: How/why is this different? I always assumed both statements to be interchangeable.

Comment: I'm not sure.  But all of the code examples that I've seen that use a lambda expression also use an *actual* type to Select into, not an anonymous type.

Comment: I've been able to do it with anonymous types. In MVC2 I used an overridable version of `.Select(x => new { Text = x.a, Value = x.b })` to get a nice and clean approach to casting entities to dropdownlists. I generally like using lambdas over using the other way (I have no word for it except "SQL like"), but that's a preference of layout.

Comment: @Flater: In your approach, the lambda variable is always being referenced.

Comment: It also used variables that didn't use the lambda variable, but an external (from outside the lambda) variable. Those work as well. But maybe purely const values don't.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
var query = dbManager.Table.Select(x=>new { column = x.column, cnst = 1 });
```